# ROS Answers SE migration: Eigen in ROS?

Tags: eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and trying to do research using ROS. My program has lots of matrix computations where I use the eigen to do that. My question is "how can I use eigen in ROS?".
I did some research on that and tried following ROS Wiki, but I have not got any luck so far. Can anybody tell me how to do that?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10940/eigen-in-ros?/) by [paul](https://answers.ros.org/users/964/paul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of ROS Electric, Eigen is a system dependency, so you shouldn't have to do anything special to use it.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, to use a ROS package, all you have to do is add

`<depend package="foo"/>` to your `manifest.xml`, and then run `rosmake`. Anything built with `rosbuild` after that will Just Work.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-08-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) on 2011-08-17**:
Eigen is included with ROS, just include  in yout manifest file.